# Akka-http exception handling (Scala)

Tags: scala, exception, akka, future, akka-http

I am using Akka-hhtp (scala) to send multiple http batch requests asynchronously to an API and wondering what is the right way to handle exceptions when the response code is other than 200 OK.

Below is some pseudo-code to demonstrate my point.

```
/* Using For comprehension here because the server API has restriction on the amount of data we can send and the time it takes them to process each request. So they require us to send multiple mini requests instead. If one of those fails, then our entire job should fail.*/

val eventuallyResponses = for {
    batches <- postBatch(payload)
} yield batches

val eventualResponses = Future.sequence(eventuallyResponses)

/* Do I need to recover here? If I don't, will the actor system terminate? */
eventualResponses.recover { case es =>
   log.warn("some message")
   List()
}

/* As I said I need to wait for all mini batch requests to complete. If one response is different than 200, then the entire job should fail. */
val result = Await.result(eventualResponses, 10.minutes)


actorSystem.terminate().oncomplete{
  case Success(_) =>
      if (result.isEmpty) =>
          /* This doesn't seem to interrupt the program */
          throw new RuntimeException("POST failed")
      } else {
          log.info("POST Successful")
      }
   case Failure(ex) =>
      log.error("error message $ex")
      throw ex
}

def postBatch(payload) = {
    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = httpClient.post(payload)

     responseFuture.flatMap{ res =>
       res.status match {
         case StatusCodes.OK => Future.successful(res)
         case _ => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("error message"))
       }
      }
}
```

The above code throws exception when we receive StatusCodes different than OK. It does go through the branch of `result.isEmpty` true, but it doesn't seem to stop/interrupt the execution of the program. I need it to do that, as this is scheduled as an Autosys job, and I need to make the job fail if at least one of the batch requests returns different response than 200 OK.

If I don't `recover` and let the exception be thrown then (when we receive non 200 status code), will the Actor System be terminated properly?

Do you know of a good way to do the above?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your case is hard to understand. Why do you use for comprehension? Why do you recover eventualResponses? You can wait for the future result by Await.ready, it doesn't throw an exception if the future fails. Also, you should wait for the actor system termination instead of adding oncomplete callback.

Comment: Hi Aleksey, thanks for your response. See answers to your questions. For comprehension is used to create multiple batch requests (this is because the server API has restriction on the amount of data we can send and the time it takes to process each request. So they require us to send multiple mini requests instead. If one of those fails, then our entire job should fail.)Do you have any good example to look at? I need the job to throw exception if any of the responses from the mini batch requests returns non 200.

Comment: @AlekseyIsachenkov I added a few explanations in the pseudo-code. Let me know if that is clear and if you have any further comments :)

Comment: For comprehension doesn't help you to send multiple requests in a way you expect. You don't need to recover the future if you don't map or flatmap it. You can match on the future result value.

Comment: `Future` does not have an `isEmpty` method, and that `for` is a no-op, so something is not quite right here. Can you give us some real code?

Comment: Thank you all for your useful comments! I am new to this and you have been very helpful already! So I have now removed the recover part, using `Await.ready` for both the `eventualResponses` and the `system` termination. Not sure how to structure that nicely. Any suggestions? @AlekseyIsachenkov what should I replace the for comprehension with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you need to throw an exception from `main` body if some responses haven't status 200.

```
def postBatch(payload: HttpRequest)(implicit system: ActorSystem, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[HttpResponse] = {
    Http().singleRequest(payload).flatMap(response => response.status match {
        case StatusCodes.OK => Future.successful(response)
        case _ => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("error message"))
    })
}

val reuests: List[HttpRequest] = List(...)
/*
You don't need for comprehension here because
val eventuallyResponses = for {
  batches <- postBatch(payload)
} yield batches

is equal to
val eventuallyResponses = postBatch(payload)

For comprehension doesn't process recursive sending. If you need it you should write it yourself by flatMap on each request future.
*/
val eventualResponses: Future[List[HttpResponse]] =
    Future.sequence(reuests.map(postBatch)) //also, its better to add some throttling logic here

//as far as i understand you need to wait for all responses and stop the actor system after that
Await.ready(eventualResponses, 10 minutes) //wait for all responses
Await.ready(actorSystem.terminate(), Duration.Inf) //wait for actor system termination

//because of Await.ready(eventualResponses, 10 minutes) we can match on the future value and expect that it should be completed  
eventualResponses.value match {
    case Some(Success(responses)) =>
        log.info("All requests completed")
    case Some(Failure(exception)) =>
        log.error("Some request failed")
        throw exception //rethrow this exception
    case None =>
        log.error("Requests timed out")
        throw RuntimeException("Requests timed out")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AlekseyIsachenkov!! This looks neat and clarifies things! in terms of the Duration.Inf when awaiting for the actor system to terminate, isn't it better to have some shorter timeout? and how should we deal with such a case when we reach the timeout?

Comment: As I understand, actor system termination time is limited by the sum of all phases in coordinated shutdown. Therefore it's better to properly configure coordinated shutdown.
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#coordinated-shutdown

Comment: wont wrapping  ```case StatusCodes.OK => Future.successful(response)
``` in a Future.successful is blocking